# Stop writing to native_stderr.log and native_stdout.log websphere application server

Tags: logging, websphere

I have a Java application deployed in websphere application server 855 version. The JVM is keep on writing to native_stderr.log and native_stdout.log and the size of the file is getting bigger. The verbose JNI is already disabled in admin console. But still the file size is growing. How to stop writing to native_stderr.log and native_stdout.log ?

Comment: What's the content that's being written?

Comment: The content written is from a thrid party library. like "*.FNT is not available" "cannot open configuration file, No such file or directory"